# Random direction bullets?

Tags: python, random, projectile

I've been working on a bullet-hell game, but when I try to make the bullets spawn in random directions and travel in a straight line, I can't seem to be able to do it. I can see that making the bullet travel +/- certain pixels in x and y axis only causes them to travel in a random pattern that seems unnatural.

My code:

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load("Bullet.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self) :

        self.rect.x += random.randrange(-10,10) 
        self.rect.y += random.randrange(-10,10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `__init__` method, you can create `self.dx` and `self.dy` variables that will be randomly chosen once upon instantiation and then stay constant every `update`:

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def init(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load("Bullet.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.dx = random.randrange(-10,10)
        self.dy = random.randrange(-10,10)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.dx
        self.rect.y += self.dy
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, turns out the solution was far more easier than I thought

Comment: @user3786223, Glad I could help. If my answer was sufficient, would you mind accepting it? Thanks